# StreamingMessageSource keeps firing when a filter is applied

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to poll an FTP directory for a certain kind of file, the polling of a directory works, but whenever I try to apply a filter to filter the files by extension, the messagesource keeps spamming messages about the file with no regard to the polling delay. Without the filters everything works fine, once I enable them my application authenticates with the FTP, downloads the file and sends the message nonstop over and over again. I have the following beans:

```
/**
 * Factory that creates the remote connection
 *
 * @return DefaultSftpSessionFactory
 */
@Bean
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory(@Value("${ftp.host}") String ftpHost,
                                                    @Value("${ftp.port}") int ftpPort,
                                                    @Value("${ftp.user}") String ftpUser,
                                                    @Value("${ftp.pass}") String ftpPass) {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    factory.setHost(ftpHost);
    factory.setPort(ftpPort);
    factory.setUser(ftpUser);
    factory.setPassword(ftpPass);

    return factory;
}

/**
 * Template to handle remote files
 *
 * @param sessionFactory SessionFactory bean
 * @return SftpRemoteFileTemplate
 */
@Bean
public SftpRemoteFileTemplate fileTemplate(DefaultSftpSessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    SftpRemoteFileTemplate template = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sessionFactory);
    template.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    template.setUseTemporaryFileName(false);
    return template;
}

/**
 * To listen to multiple directories, declare multiples of this bean with the same inbound channel
 *
 * @param fileTemplate FileTemplate bean
 * @return MessageSource
 */
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "deeplinkAutomated", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "6000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"))
public MessageSource inboundChannelAdapter(SftpRemoteFileTemplate fileTemplate) {
    SftpStreamingMessageSource source = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(fileTemplate);
    source.setRemoteDirectory("/upload");
    source.setFilter(new CompositeFileListFilter<>(
            Arrays.asList(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>(), new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.trg"))
    ));

    return source;
}

/**
 * Listener that activates on new messages on the specified input channel
 *
 * @return MessageHandler
 */
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "deeplinkAutomated")
public MessageHandler handler(JobLauncher jobLauncher, Job deeplinkBatch) {
    return message -> {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SFTPFileInfo info = gson.fromJson((String) message.getHeaders().get("file_remoteFileInfo"), SFTPFileInfo.class);
        System.out.println("File to download: " + info.getFilename().replace(".trg", ".xml"));
    };
}
```

Comment: How does it work if you change the `CompositeFileListFilter` to the `ChainFileListFilter`? May we have some DEBUG logs to be sure that the story is really about the same file? Don't you have some error in the end which causes a file to rolled back from the filter store?

Comment: The ChainFileListFilter does not change the problem, I have pasted the DEBUG logs from the start of the spring application [here](https://pastebin.com/98WRV6BA) in the logs you can see that the ftp connections do not have a 6 second delay between them but follow one after the other, this is not the case when the I comment out the code from the filters, which you can see in [the following logs](https://pastebin.com/kpR8jzhn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` is not suitable for SFTP files. The returned `LsEntry` doesn't match previously stored in the `HashSet`: just their hashes are different!

Consider to use a `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` instead.

Also it would be better to configure a `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` for the `isSharedSession`:

```
/**
 * @param isSharedSession true if the session is to be shared.
 */
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory(boolean isSharedSession) {
```

To avoid session recreation on each polling task.

you don't have a 6 seconds delay between calls because you have a `maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"`. That means poll remote files until they are there in remote dir. In your case with the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` you always end up with the same file by the hash reason.